# How to inject dataSource to jUnit for Integration Testing in SpringFramework 2

Tags: java, spring, junit, datasource, integration-testing

I have the following dataSource defined in my spring-beans.xml file which I use in order to connect in my remote database :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sample"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="root"/>

</bean>
```

I am building a couple of jUnit integration tests that I want to run. Some of the functions that get called from these tests use this datasource in order to access my database. When I deploy my project the dataSource is injected according to beans configuration that I have done.

For these tests that will run independently of the web application how can I inject this dataSource in order to access the database ?

I use the SpringFramework 2.5.6 version and jUnit4 for my tests.

Comment: "SpringFramework 2.5.6" that's a pretty old version..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Integration test with Spring

Sample jUnit Integration test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "spring-beans.xml")
public class MyIntegrationTest {

   @Autowired
   DataSource dataSource;

}
```

Read more in [Spring Framework Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/) > [Integration Testing](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing) > [JDBC Testing Support](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#integration-testing-support-jdbc)

### [Database testing](http://www.unitils.org/tutorial-database.html) with [Unitils](http://www.unitils.org/summary.html)

> Unitils greatly reduces this complexity, making database testing easy and maintainable.

Unitils offers [features for unit testing when working with Spring](http://www.unitils.org/tutorial-spring.html).

```
public abstract class BaseDAOTest extends UnitilsJUnit4 {

    @TestDataSource
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Before    
    public void initializeDao() {
        BaseDAO dao = getDaoUnderTest();
        dao.setDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    protected abstract BaseDAO getDaoUnderTest();
}
```

Comment: The dataSource is added correctly but when I execute the tests I get an : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/Assume$AssumptionViolatedException ... To which class could this  exception refer ?

Comment: This looks like classpath problem - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9874369/why-getting-the-assumptionviolatedexception-junit-4-8-2

Comment: Probably you have two version of junit on classpath, post new question with more information.

Comment: Well in my classpath I have only one version of junit , version 4.8.1 ... I read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12497857/trying-to-run-junit-test-on-service-level-of-spring-webflow-project-assumeassu that the solution to this error is to downgrade to junit 4.4 but when I did this I got this error " java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [tests/spring-beans.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist" This is really strange because it is in the same place that I had it before (same folder with my test cases)