# Entries missing in database when using Spring jdbcTemplate batch insert in a multithreaded environment

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, jdbctemplate

I am trying to add multiple records into an Oracle 12c database using a simple spring jdbcTemplate call to batchUpdate() method. The code that makes the batchUpdate() call is in my DAO class. However the code that calls the service method is multi-threaded.

This is what my DAO class looks like (there are more like this):

```
public void batchInsertSessionSignature(final List<SessionSignature> sessionSignatures, DataSource dataSource) {

    Assert.notNull(sessionSignatures, "Checking to see if the SessionSignature objects passed in are null");

    if (dataSource != null) {
        jdbcTemplate.setDataSource(dataSource);
    }

    if (!sessionSignatures.isEmpty()) {

        log.debug("Inserting batch entries into lev_session_signature_temp of size: " + sessionSignatures.size());

        int[] res = jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(insertSessionSig, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

            @Override
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement pstmt, int i) throws SQLException {

                SessionSignature ss = sessionSignatures.get(i);
                String created_date = sdf.format(ss.getCreated_date());

                pstmt.setLong(1, ss.getId());
                pstmt.setString(2, ss.getHost());
                pstmt.setString(3, ss.getSession_id());
                pstmt.setString(4, ss.getIp_address());         
                pstmt.setString(5, ss.getAccountName());
                try {
                    pstmt.setInt(6, sysInfoBean.getSysinfoID(ss.getSysinfo()));
                    pstmt.setDate(7, new Date(sdf.parse(created_date).getTime()));
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                pstmt.setString(8, ss.getCountry());
                pstmt.setInt(9, ss.getAccountID());
                pstmt.setString(10, ss.getBusinessUnit());
            }

            @Override
            public int getBatchSize() {
                return sessionSignatures.size();
            }
        });

        log.debug(res.length + " entries inserted into lev_session_signature_temp");

    }
}
```

This is the service layer method that makes the call to the DAO classes (the method is thread safe)

```
@Transactional(propagation= Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public synchronized void writeTargetDaoEntries(TargetDao targetDao, DataSource dataSource, ArrayList<SessionSignature> tgtSessionSignatures, 
        ArrayList<Session> tgtSession, ArrayList<SearchGroup> tgtSearchGroup, ArrayList<Search> tgtSearches, 
        ArrayList<LuceneEvent> tgtEvents, ArrayList<EventAnalysisDaoUtil> eventAnalysisList) throws Exception {

    targetDao.batchInsertSessionSignatures(tgtSessionSignatures, dataSource);
    targetDao.batchInsertUserSessions(tgtSession, dataSource);
    targetDao.batchInsertSearchGroups(tgtSearchGroup, dataSource);
    targetDao.batchInsertSearches(tgtSearches, dataSource);
    targetDao.batchInsertEvents(tgtEvents, dataSource);
    targetDao.batchInsertEventAnalysis(eventAnalysisList, dataSource);

}
```

My spring configuration looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd"> 

<context:annotation-config/>
<context:property-placeholder location="app.properties"/>

<bean id="dataSourceQa" class="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceFactory"
    factory-method="getPoolDataSource" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="connectionFactoryClassName" 
value="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" />
    <property name="user" value="${qaTargetId}" />
    <property name="password" value="${qaTargetPswd}" />
    <property name="URL" value="${qaTargetURL}" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="2" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSourceProd" class="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceFactory"
    factory-method="getPoolDataSource" lazy-init="true">
    <property name="connectionFactoryClassName" 
value="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" />
    <property name="user" value="${prodSourceId}" />
    <property name="password" value="${prodSourcePswd}" />
    <property name="URL" value="${prodSourceURL}" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="2" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
</bean>

<!-- JDBC Template Configuration -->        
<bean id = "jdbcTemplate" class = "org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name = "dataSource" ref = "dataSourceQa"></property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceQa" />
</bean>

<bean id="taskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="10" />
    <property name="WaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
</bean>

<!-- DAO Bean Configuration -->
<bean id = "eventDaoBean" class = "com.uptodate.lucene.tool.analysis.transfer.oracleDao.EventDao" />
<bean id = "searchDaoBean" class = "com.uptodate.lucene.tool.analysis.transfer.oracleDao.SearchDao" />
<bean id = "searchGroupDaoBean" class = "com.uptodate.lucene.tool.analysis.transfer.oracleDao.SearchGroupDao" />
<bean id = "userSessionDaoBean" class = "com.uptodate.lucene.tool.analysis.transfer.oracleDao.UserSessionDao" />
<bean id = "sessionSignatureDaoBean" class = "com.uptodate.lucene.tool.analysis.transfer.oracleDao.SessionSignatureDao" />
<bean id = "eventAnalysisDaoBean" class = "com.uptodate.lucene.tool.analysis.transfer.oracleDao.EventAnalysisDao" />
<bean id = "dailySummaryDaoBean" class = "com.uptodate.lucene.tool.analysis.transfer.oracleDao.DailySummaryDao" />
<bean id = "keyGeneratorBean" class = "com.uptodate.lucene.tool.analysis.transfer.oracleDao.KeyGenerator" />
<bean id = "machineLearningDaoBean" class = "com.uptodate.lucene.tool.analysis.transfer.oracleDao.MachineLearningDao" />
<bean id = "sourceDaoBean" abstract = "true" class = "com.uptodate.lucene.tool.analysis.transfer.oracleDao.SourceDao" />
<bean id = "desktopSourceDaoBean" class = "com.uptodate.lucene.tool.analysis.transfer.oracleDao.DesktopSourceDao" />        
<bean id = "mobileSourceDaoBean" class = "com.uptodate.lucene.tool.analysis.transfer.oracleDao.MobileSourceDao" />
<bean id = "webSourceDaoBean" class = "com.uptodate.lucene.tool.analysis.transfer.oracleDao.WebSourceDao" />
<bean id = "tempTableDaoBean" class = "com.uptodate.lucene.tool.analysis.transfer.oracleDao.TempTableDao" />

<bean id = "targetDaoBean" class = "com.uptodate.lucene.tool.analysis.transfer.oracleDao.TargetDao">
    <constructor-arg ref = "eventDaoBean" />
    <constructor-arg ref = "searchDaoBean" />
    <constructor-arg ref = "searchGroupDaoBean" />
    <constructor-arg ref = "userSessionDaoBean" />
    <constructor-arg ref = "sessionSignatureDaoBean" />
    <constructor-arg ref = "eventAnalysisDaoBean" />
</bean>

<!-- Parser Bean Configuration -->
<bean id = "userSessionParserBean" class = "com.uptodate.lucene.tool.analysis.transfer.parser.UserSessionParser" scope = "prototype" />
<bean id = "searchParserBean" class = "com.uptodate.lucene.tool.analysis.transfer.parser.SearchParser" scope = "prototype" />
<bean id = "searchGroupParserBean" class = "com.uptodate.lucene.tool.analysis.transfer.parser.SearchGroupParser" scope = "prototype" />
<bean id = "eventParserBean" abstract = "true" class = "com.uptodate.lucene.tool.analysis.transfer.parser.EventParser" scope = "prototype" />
<bean id = "mobileEventParserBean" class = "com.uptodate.lucene.tool.analysis.transfer.parser.MobileEventParser" scope = "prototype" />
<bean id = "webEventParserBean" class = "com.uptodate.lucene.tool.analysis.transfer.parser.WebEventParser" scope = "prototype" />

<bean id = "logParserBean" class = "com.uptodate.lucene.tool.analysis.transfer.LogParser" scope = "prototype">
    <constructor-arg ref = "keyGeneratorBean" />
    <constructor-arg ref = "searchParserBean" />
    <constructor-arg ref = "searchGroupParserBean" />
    <constructor-arg ref = "userSessionParserBean" />
</bean>

<!-- Transfer Bean Configuration -->
<bean id = "dailySummaryGeneratorBean" class = "com.uptodate.lucene.tool.analysis.transfer.DailySummaryGenerator" />

<!-- Util Bean Configuration -->
<bean id = "sysInfoBean" class = "com.uptodate.lucene.tool.analysis.vo.SysInfo">
    <property name = "dataSource" ref = "dataSourceProd" />
</bean>
```

I have tried adding support for transactions hoping that would help make sure the entries are committed to the database but that did not help. I can see in the code that all entries sent to the database were written to it but when I check the number of records in the database the same number is not reflected. I'm not sure if this is because of the multithreaded nature of the code that a batch of entires is overwritten somehow? Using 1 thread seems to work fine making me believe its a multithreading issue but I'm not sure where the problem is. Any help on this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Your dao is seriously flawed. `JdbcTemplate` is a singleton. You are changing the `DataSource` of a singleton now imagine 10 threads are changing and changing the datasource suddenly each thread is writing/reading/operating on the last datasource that has been set. I also see no trace of multithreading in your service so not sure where that is coming from.

Comment: You might be right about the jdbcTemplate issue in the DAO. The multithreading is happening in a different class. The workflow basically reads some data from the database, the main list is broken down into smaller sublists for each thread to process -> Process it using multiple threads -> Each thread writes its subset of the result back to the DB. So jdbcTemplate should be a prototype instead then?

Comment: I don't see why you are switching the datasource... That is pretty dangerous, not to mention imho quite ugly from a design perspective passing a `DataSource` around.

Comment: I agree but I need to do that because when I am testing this I need to use a different database to write versus to read. In production I can get away with just using a single datasource in which case I don't need to pass it around or even change it.

Comment: Also I just double checked, jdbcTemplate is thread safe so using the singleton instance in the DAO class shouldn't be an issue. Somehow the entries being written in the DB are not being committed by each write operation is what it seems.

Comment: It's not a problem to set the Datasource, he is not switching, he's assigning it if it is null, and this is never the case because it is injected from spring (I agree the design is seriously owful, what about injecting the datasource like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935729/how-to-inject-datasource-to-junit-for-integration-testing-in-springframework-2)

Comment: Technically I am switching it because I am using a different datasource to read and then a different one to write but only when I am testing. When I start my test I need my datasource to point to the production database and when I am writing it needs to go to the QA database. The solution in the link works if I just want to use a single datasource throughout the test. However that still doesn't tell me what I am doing wrong in terms of multi threading and not seeing the correct number of entries in the DB.

Comment: It may happen that your `writeTargetDaoEntries()` starts a transaction on one `Connection` (from one datasource), while the write goes to a different `Connection` from different datasource. If this is the case, then the transaction is committed on the first `Connection` and not the second, hence no commit on the second happens at all.

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy It seems like a commit overwrite might be happening from multiple threads using multiple connections to the database but the datasource for all the writes is the same and jdbctemplate is thread safe here so it should not play a part in the problem. So from what I understand each thread will pull one connection from the pool to be able to do the write and since the method is synchronized only one thread will have access to write. So I don't understand how a different thread could interfere with the ongoing operation?

Comment: The situation I describe here is that *one* connection is used to start/commit a transaction, but *another* connection is used to execute writes. I'm not sure whether this is the case you face, but did you try to stop changing the datasource and just make sure that both `TransactionManager` and `JdbcTemplate` use the same datasource?

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy Yes. My TransactionManager is set to default to the QA datasource and jdbcTemplate is set to default to it also, if its not then I set it so they are both the same when doing the writes.

Comment: IMHO your whole issue is due to your setup. However transactions and multithreading don't work together a transaction is thread bound, so if you are sharing those things it will actually break. However you have synchronized a method then why bother with multi threading?

Comment: @M.Deinum I have tried this without having it as a transaction but that had the same issue. I added the transaction support to make sure the entries were being committed to the DB. As far as the synchronized write is concerned without it I run into a duplicate entry issue when writing.

Comment: Seems like you are trying to fix something you shouldn't be fixing in the first place. Looks like your partitioning (dividing in chunks) isn't all up to it, and the fact that your transaction demarcation is wrong it won't work. You cannot switch datasources as you would also need to switch the one used by the transaction manager else it will start a t transaction on the wrong connection. Problem is it already started a transaction before you switch it. However with the few snippets in place in this question it is impossible to answer your question.

Comment: @M.Deinum I understand what you mean but that is not what I am trying to do. I don't switch the datasource between two separate transactions. Each thread will have its own connection that it will grab from the connection pool and each of those connections is governed by a datasource. Once a connection is obtained and used there are no more switches and another transaction will have its independent connection from the pool so there is no sharing either. On further investigation I think the problem is more geared towards how the database commits the records and not the code.